# Arguments bundle not getting populated in my fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragments, each containing a single control, and a textview, and they get stacked on top of each other. This works fine. What isn't working is that each of these fragments gets created with the newInstance method so that I can pass so data to it (questionID and question Text). The question text is meant to display above the control (whether that be spinner, radio group, whatever), but its always blank and I keep getting null pointer errors if I try to call that argument directly.

fragment code

```
public class RadioFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mQuestionID;
private String mQuestionText;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private Button mSaveButton;
private TextView mQuestion;

/**
 * @param questionID Parameter 1.
 * @param questionText Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment RadioFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static RadioFragment newInstance(String questionID, String questionText) {
    RadioFragment fragment = new RadioFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, questionID);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, questionText);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public RadioFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mQuestionID = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mQuestionText = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio, container, false);

    //set the question text

    mQuestion = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.questionText);
    mQuestion.setText(mQuestionText);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    //public void onButton(String questionType, String question);
}
}
```

the part in MainActivity where the fragments is instantiated:

```
String questionID = "someID";
 String questionText = "This is a sample question";
// Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            RadioFragment firstFragment = RadioFragment.newInstance(questionID, questionText);
            //RadioFragment firstFragment = new RadioFragment(questionID, questionText);

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, firstFragment, "fragment" + i).commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this line is causing problems:

```
firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
```

Comment it out and check if problem still exists. Probably your `Bundle` doesn't contain keys: ARG_PARAM1, ARG_PARAM2.

Comment: Yep this was absolutely it! Thank you. This was default code generated from the IDE when I created the activity and it was basically overiding my arguments with the Intent extras (of which there were none). Thank you!